# Не получается написать цикл для прохода по JSON

Tags: python, json, циклы

Всем добрый день, заранее прошу прощения за возможно глупый вопрос, я совсем новичок. Есть код, выуживающий статусы из твиттера по определенному поисковому запросу. Нужно выловить много статусов, но я что-то никак не могу понять, как пройтись циклом внутри json файла:( 
заранее спасибо!

```
import urllib.request as ur
from twurl import augment
import json
import re
url = augment('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=python',
{'count': '2'} )
connection = ur.urlopen(url)
data = connection.read().decode('utf-8')
info = json.loads(data)
status = info["statuses"]
#print (json.dumps(status, indent=4))
#как записать циклом следующие строчки?
print ('Status 1:',info["statuses"][0]["text"].encode("utf-8"))
print ('Status 2:',info["statuses"][1]["text"].encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нужно выделить объект, по которому происходит итерация. В данном случае это `info["statuses"]` (к его элементами происходит обращение по индексам). А дальше, нужно просто сделать итерацию по элементам этого объекта в виде цикла:

```
for status in info["statuses"]:
    print('Status 1:', status["text"].encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Только utf-8 здесь не распознает русские символы, хотя, как я почитала, вроде бы должен. Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: @Aranea, попробуйте убрать `.encode("utf-8")`, мне кажется он не нужен.